# Magento 2 site does not work after migrating to another server

Tags: magento2, hosting

I've recently moved a Magento 2 site to a new server. I'm facing a strange problem. Whenever I hit the URL in any browser, it downloads a system file instead of taking me to the site. It doesn't generate any error log. I've tried with different browsers but the problem persists.

I removed all the cache files and still doesn't work. I've never had this issue. Any idea what might cause this error?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Please check permission.

Comment: I have. I changed folder permission to 755 but still doesn't work. @AnasMansuri

Comment: let me know which error are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Apache server rewrites are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

php is not enabled or handler not set properly.
this is why you download php as text. you need to execute php.

if you run cPanel then go to profile customization and install php-fpm or mod_php.